# Fill Cells Value, Color in another Sheet in using EXCEL UDF

Tags: excel, validation, vba

This function check JMBG (unique citizenship numbers) and PIB numbers (for companies)

if they are incorrect function returnes error messages.

I want that my function also creates new worksheet to put all wrong JMBG or PIB numbers with error messages.

Here is an example:

Worksheet1 contains an example in cell A1:

`0805988212987`

when I call CheckID(A1)    --->it returnes me JMBG is correct

`1234`

it returns me error message

Now I want that my function immediately creates new worksheet (`workhseet2`) in which will be put
`12345` and error message...colored as red if possible

It means, that I have `worksheet1` where I have lot of numbers and I check them all.

I want to move into new worksheet all numbers that have error messages and color that messages with red or some other color.

Bottom is my current function. First is the main function which calls back other 2.

Example in Excel sheet:

```
0805988212987   JMBG is correct
20538350             PIB is correct
abcdef           ERROR: Function can not check JMBG nor PIB ...
ABCDEF           ERROR: Cell contains only UPPER letters. Numeric input ...
AVGsgh           ERROR: There is error because cell contains only LOWER and UPPER...
Marko Dragovic    ERROR: Wrong input data. Cell is empty. Must be numeric and 8 or 13 
12345           ERROR: Excel cell limit is not correct. It should be 8 or 13, and numeric.
            ERROR: Wrong input data. Cell is empty. Must be numeric and 8 or 13 length
JMBG          ERROR: Cell contains only UPPER letters. Numeric input of cell not achieved 
0         ERROR: Excel cell limit is not correct. It should be 8 or 13, and numeric.
```

I want all error to be automaticaly moved into new sheet and colored red.

```
Function CheckID(ByRef rng As Range) As String
Dim str  As String, strMsg As String
Dim objRegEx1 As Object, objRegEx2 As Object, objRegEx3 As Object
Dim sret As String

str = rng.Value

Set objRegEx1 = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
Set objRegEx2 = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
Set objRegEx3 = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
Set objRegEx4 = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
Set objRegEx5 = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
Set objRegEx6 = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
Set objRegEx7 = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
objRegEx1.IgnoreCase = False
objRegEx1.Global = True
objRegEx2.IgnoreCase = False
objRegEx2.Global = True
objRegEx3.IgnoreCase = False
objRegEx3.Global = True
objRegEx4.IgnoreCase = False
objRegEx4.Global = True
objRegEx5.IgnoreCase = False
objRegEx5.Global = True
objRegEx6.IgnoreCase = False
objRegEx6.Global = True
objRegEx7.IgnoreCase = False
objRegEx7.Global = True

objRegEx1.Pattern = "^\d+$" '-- only numbers
objRegEx2.Pattern = "^[a-z]+$" '-- only lower letters
objRegEx3.Pattern = "^[A-Z]+$" '-- only upper letters
objRegEx4.Pattern = "^[a-zA-Z]+$" '-- only lower/upper letters
objRegEx5.Pattern = "^[a-z\d]+$" '-- numbers and lower leters
objRegEx6.Pattern = "^[A-Z\d]+$" '-- numbers and upper letters
objRegEx7.Pattern = "^[a-zA-Z\d]+$" '-- numbers and lower/upper letters

If objRegEx1.Test(str) Then
    If (Len(str) <> 13) And (Len(str) <> 8) Then
    strMsg = "ERROR: Cell numeric limit is not correct. It should be 8 or 13."
    ElseIf Len(str) = 13 Then
    strMsg = Check_JMBG(CStr(str))
    ElseIf Len(str) = 8 Then
    strMsg = Check_PIB(CStr(str))
    End If
ElseIf objRegEx2.Test(str) Then
    strMsg = "ERROR: Function can not check JMBG nor PIB because cell contains only LOWER letters. Numeric input of cell not achieved"
ElseIf objRegEx3.Test(str) Then
    strMsg = "ERROR: Cell contains only UPPER letters. Numeric input of cell not achieved and thus nor JMBG nor PIB is going to be checked"
ElseIf objRegEx4.Test(str) Then
    strMsg = "ERROR: Cell contains only LOWER and UPPER letters. Numeric input of cell not achieved"
ElseIf objRegEx5.Test(str) Then
    strMsg = "ERROR: Cell contains NUMBERS and LOWER letters. Function can't check JMBG or PIB because they are not entered correct. Numeric input of cell not achieved"
ElseIf objRegEx6.Test(str) Then
    strMsg = "ERROR: There is no JMBG or PIB in the valid form in the cell. Cell contains NUMBERS and UPPER letters. Numeric input of cell not achieved"
ElseIf objRegEx7.Test(str) Then
    strMsg = "ERROR: Because cell contains NUMBERS, LOWER and UPPER letters, numeric input of cell is not achieved. Enter correct data"
ElseIf IsEmpty(cell) Then
    strMsg = "ERROR: Cell is empty"
Else
    strMsg = "ERROR: Cell not satisfying input arguments. There are special characters in the cell or it is empty. Numeric input of cell not achieved"
End If

CheckID = strMsg
End Function

Public Function Check_PIB(PIB As String)

'Function for checking PIB
'Initialization of all values inside PIB, 8 numbers, 1 control number
Dim c0 As Integer
Dim c1 As Integer
Dim c2 As Integer
Dim c3 As Integer
Dim c4 As Integer
Dim c5 As Integer
Dim c6 As Integer
Dim c7 As Integer
Dim c8 As Integer
Dim zadnji As String

last = Right(PIB, 1)
PIB = Left(PIB, 8)
If Len(PIB) <> 8 Then
   Check_PIB = "PIB is correct"
Else
       c8 = (CInt(Mid(PIB, 1, 1)) + 10) Mod 10
       If c8 = 0 Then
         c8 = 10
       End If
       c8 = (c8 * 2) Mod 11
       c7 = (CInt(Mid(PIB, 2, 1)) + c8) Mod 10
       If c7 = 0 Then
         c7 = 10
       End If
       c7 = (c7 * 2) Mod 11
       c6 = (CInt(Mid(PIB, 3, 1)) + c7) Mod 10
       If c6 = 0 Then
         c6 = 10
       End If
       c6 = (c6 * 2) Mod 11
       c5 = (CInt(Mid(PIB, 4, 1)) + c6) Mod 10
       If c5 = 0 Then
         c5 = 10
       End If
       c5 = (c5 * 2) Mod 11
       c4 = (CInt(Mid(PIB, 5, 1)) + c5) Mod 10
       If c4 = 0 Then
         c4 = 10
       End If
       c4 = (c4 * 2) Mod 11
       c3 = (CInt(Mid(PIB, 6, 1)) + c4) Mod 10
       If c3 = 0 Then
         c3 = 10
       End If
       c3 = (c3 * 2) Mod 11
       c2 = (CInt(Mid(PIB, 7, 1)) + c3) Mod 10
       If c2 = 0 Then
         c2 = 10
       End If
       c2 = (c2 * 2) Mod 11
       c1 = (CInt(Mid(PIB, 8, 1)) + c2) Mod 10
       If c1 = 0 Then
         c1 = 10
       End If
       c1 = (c1 * 2) Mod 11
       c0 = (11 - c1) Mod 10
       If c0 <> last Then
        Check_PIB = "PIB is correct"
       Else
        Check_PIB = "Error: Wrong PIB. Not valid"
       End If
End If
End Function

Function Check_JMBG(JMBG As String) As String
    If (Len(JMBG) <> 13) Then
        Check_JMBG = "ERR: Length of JMBG is not 13!"
    ElseIf Not IsNumeric(JMBG) Then
        Check_JMBG = "ERR: JMBG contains non-numerical characters"
    ElseIf Not fctBlnCheckDate(JMBG) Then
        Check_JMBG = "ERR: Wrong JMBG date entered!"
    ElseIf fctBlnCheckSum(JMBG) Then
        Check_JMBG = "ERR: Wrong JMBG checksum!"
    Else
        Check_JMBG = "JMBG is correct"
    End If
End Function

Private Function fctBlnCheckDate(JMBG As String) As Boolean
    Dim intDay As Integer, intMonth As Integer, intYear As Integer
    Dim datCheck As Date

    intDay = Int(Left(JMBG, 2))
    intMonth = Int(Mid$(JMBG, 3, 2))
    intYear = Int(Mid$(JMBG, 5, 3)) + 1000

    datCheck = DateSerial(intYear, intMonth, intDay)

    fctBlnCheckDate = _
        (Year(datCheck) = intYear) And _
        (Month(datCheck) = intMonth) And _
        (Day(datCheck) = intDay)

End Function

Private Function fctBlnCheckSum(JMBG As String) As Boolean
    Dim intCheckSum As Integer, i As Integer

    For i = 1 To 13
        intCheckSum = intCheckSum + Int(Mid$(JMBG, i, 1))
        Next i
End Function
```

Comment: It is better to ask a small question instead of a big task. I think your question can be break down to `How to create new worksheet`, `How to write into new worksheet` , `How to use conditional formatting in VBA`

Comment: It is not big task. I just wanted to show my all code since it is better to understand. I found some codes to show my msg into other colores but I cant implement it here. That is the reason why I put all code here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT** This will not work for UDF.

is this what you looking for?

use `logging` in your code if you want to log it down

```
Sub logging(ByVal val As String, ByVal msg As String)
Dim logWs As Worksheet
Err.Clear
On Error Resume Next
Set logWs = Worksheets("Error Log")
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    Set logWs = Worksheets.Add
    logWs.Name = "Error Log"
End If
On Error GoTo 0

With logWs
    Height = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    .Cells(Height + 1, 1).Value = val
    .Cells(Height + 1, 2).Value = msg
    .Cells(Height + 1, 2).Font.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0) ' RED in color
End With
Set logWs = Nothing

End Sub

Sub testing()
    logging "123", "ERR"
End Sub
```

**EDIT**
as request, it is assuming all your error message starts with "ERROR:"

```
Function CheckID(ByRef rng As Range) As String
    Dim str  As String, strMsg As String
    Dim objRegEx1 As Object, objRegEx2 As Object, objRegEx3 As Object
    Dim sret As String

    str = rng.Value

    Set objRegEx1 = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    Set objRegEx2 = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    Set objRegEx3 = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    Set objRegEx4 = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    Set objRegEx5 = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    Set objRegEx6 = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    Set objRegEx7 = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    objRegEx1.IgnoreCase = False
    objRegEx1.Global = True
    objRegEx2.IgnoreCase = False
    objRegEx2.Global = True
    objRegEx3.IgnoreCase = False
    objRegEx3.Global = True
    objRegEx4.IgnoreCase = False
    objRegEx4.Global = True
    objRegEx5.IgnoreCase = False
    objRegEx5.Global = True
    objRegEx6.IgnoreCase = False
    objRegEx6.Global = True
    objRegEx7.IgnoreCase = False
    objRegEx7.Global = True

    objRegEx1.Pattern = "^\d+$" '-- only numbers
    objRegEx2.Pattern = "^[a-z]+$" '-- only lower letters
    objRegEx3.Pattern = "^[A-Z]+$" '-- only upper letters
    objRegEx4.Pattern = "^[a-zA-Z]+$" '-- only lower/upper letters
    objRegEx5.Pattern = "^[a-z\d]+$" '-- numbers and lower leters
    objRegEx6.Pattern = "^[A-Z\d]+$" '-- numbers and upper letters
    objRegEx7.Pattern = "^[a-zA-Z\d]+$" '-- numbers and lower/upper letters

    If objRegEx1.Test(str) Then
        If (Len(str) <> 13) And (Len(str) <> 8) Then
        strMsg = "ERROR: Cell numeric limit is not correct. It should be 8 or 13."
        ElseIf Len(str) = 13 Then
        strMsg = Check_JMBG(CStr(str))
        ElseIf Len(str) = 8 Then
        strMsg = Check_PIB(CStr(str))
        End If
    ElseIf objRegEx2.Test(str) Then
        strMsg = "ERROR: Function can not check JMBG nor PIB because cell contains only LOWER letters. Numeric input of cell not achieved"
    ElseIf objRegEx3.Test(str) Then
        strMsg = "ERROR: Cell contains only UPPER letters. Numeric input of cell not achieved and thus nor JMBG nor PIB is going to be checked"
    ElseIf objRegEx4.Test(str) Then
        strMsg = "ERROR: Cell contains only LOWER and UPPER letters. Numeric input of cell not achieved"
    ElseIf objRegEx5.Test(str) Then
        strMsg = "ERROR: Cell contains NUMBERS and LOWER letters. Function can't check JMBG or PIB because they are not entered correct. Numeric input of cell not achieved"
    ElseIf objRegEx6.Test(str) Then
        strMsg = "ERROR: There is no JMBG or PIB in the valid form in the cell. Cell contains NUMBERS and UPPER letters. Numeric input of cell not achieved"
    ElseIf objRegEx7.Test(str) Then
        strMsg = "ERROR: Because cell contains NUMBERS, LOWER and UPPER letters, numeric input of cell is not achieved. Enter correct data"
    ElseIf IsEmpty(cell) Then
        strMsg = "ERROR: Cell is empty"
    Else
        strMsg = "ERROR: Cell not satisfying input arguments. There are special characters in the cell or it is empty. Numeric input of cell not achieved"
    End If
    'Modified by: Larry
    'Modified Date: 31-01-2013
    'Take Log in "Error Log" Sheet if it's an error
    If InStr(UCase(strMsg), "ERROR:") > 0 Then
        logging str, strMsg
    End If

    CheckID = strMsg
End Function
```

Comment: Yes it is what I want. How can I implement it in my code above were my messages are ?

Comment: Hi, please see my edit, you need to unify your error message from `ERR:` to `ERROR:`

Comment: It gives me not results. Perhaps becuase of Sub. Can you transform Sub into Function format. All my code is under function, and all are functions, none is sub. Than I hope it will probably work

Comment: it has nothing to do with sub/function. Their difference is function can return Val/Object, sub does not. You can use `CheckID("abcdef")` to test. And make sure you include my `logging` sub

Comment: Um, I know what the problem is, your function is a UDF. It can only write to the cell it's caller in.

Comment: Above you have example in Excel worksheet where I have started my code on several inputs into column A. Do that like I and my code will output you several messages like above (after you call CheckID(A1) into column B an example). First two are correct. Other are ERRORS. I need errors to be moved into new sheet and colored red.

Comment: if you call `CheckID("abcdef")` in VBE it will work, it won't work in Excel Cell like `=CheckID(A1)`. This **can** be achieve by some workaround using `global variables` `Application.onTime` , `Workbook_open` events.

Comment: In Short, my code **WON"T** work for you in Excel, but in VBA only. You need to search something like `Fill Cells Value, Color in another Sheet in using EXCEL UDF` to make it work.

Comment: It returnes me like this: #Value!. But when JMBG and PIB are correct it gives me good messages like: JMBG is correct and PIB is correct. Only when errors are, it gives me: #Value!. I know it will works when I call that in VBA. But my code worked in Excel as: CheckID(A1) and to all cells, till I added your function. That function is what I need, but it has to be global for all use, not only for special numbers or one numer like you said in previous msg

Comment: MarkoD, I over-simplified your question. Your **REAL** problem is **Fill Cells Value, Color in another Sheet in using EXCEL UDF**. As I mentioned, **NORMALLY** you cannot write into B1 if you are calling the function from A1, you need to do a **TRICK**.

Comment: I figured it out just now. I had some extra non neccessary code that I added by mistake when copy this of yours. Shit happens. Thanks man. It works just fine.

Comment: what? I don't understand how I solved your question X| .  you are able to update the log?

Comment: I did not update it. I just run it by itself and it worked for one simple number as you said. Than I transformed Sun into Function and called it under my messages and with some blessing it worked. It is not important now. You showed me code that is opening new sheet with colored messages. That is important. :)